# Calculate column from two others using a function with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, apologies if this question is repeated but I'm unable to solve my problem using the explanation in similar questions...

I have a funcion that takes two parameters into account (longitud and latitude) and then it enters in Google API to extract the city and the country of these coordinates. This funcion is the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
def getplace(lat, lon):
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
    url += "latlng=%s,%s&sensor=false" % (lat, lon)
    v = urlopen(url).read()
    j = json.loads(v)
    components = j['results'][0]['address_components']
    country = town = None
    for c in components:
        if "country" in c['types']:
            country = c['long_name']
        if "administrative_area_level_2" in c['types']:
            town = c['long_name']
    return town, country
```

I also have a database with items where most of them (but not all) contains a field with the longitud and a DIFFERENT field with the latitude. There is also some data missing in some rows.

```
reference   name    lon        lat
0           name1   34.0055    1.0041
1           name1   NaN        NaN
2           name1   39.5632    3.6854
....
```

How can I create a new field attached to the DataFrame that cointains the calculated value?

I have tried the following statements with no success:

```
df['city'] = getplace(df['lon'], df['lat'])
```

And:

```
df['city'] = df.apply(lambda x : coords(x['lon'], x['lat']) , axis=1)
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:
So I changed the full code to this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
def getplace(lat, lon):
    if np.isnan(lat)==False:
        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
        url += "latlng=%s,%s&sensor=false" % (lat, lon)
        v = urlopen(url).read()
        j = json.loads(v)
        components = j['results'][0]['address_components']
        country = town = None
        for c in components:
            if "country" in c['types']:
                country = c['long_name']
            if "administrative_area_level_2" in c['types']:
                town = c['long_name']
        return town, country

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('items.csv')
df['city']=df.apply(lambda x : getplace(x['lat'], x['lon']) , axis=1)
```

It still does not work showing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bffdb49e289b> in <module>()
----> 1 df['city']=df.apply(lambda x : getplace(x['lat'], x['lon']) , axis=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6002                          args=args,
   6003                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6004         return op.get_result()
   6005 
   6006     def applymap(self, func):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-15-bffdb49e289b> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['city']=df.apply(lambda x : getplace(x['lat'], x['lon']) , axis=1)

<ipython-input-10-ff447dcff3e8> in getplace(lat, lon)
      7         v = urlopen(url).read()
      8         j = json.loads(v)
----> 9         components = j['results'][0]['address_components']
     10         country = town = None
     11         for c in components:

IndexError: ('list index out of range', 'occurred at index 3')
```

The following is a simplified version of the file I'm trying to work with:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y3vtwage5kqxKWZIdQEwpy5qIP2KAGNT
Thank you very much

Comment: Your second approach looks like idiomatic pandas, but `coords` is nowhere defined (and should probably just be `getplace`?) You will have to do handle the case of `NaN` inputs in `getplace` though.

Comment: what do you mean by calculated value ? Are you trying to use your function for df['city'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second example works as expected (and would be idiomatic pandas) if you replace `coords` with `getplace` and make sure to take care of the rows containing `NaN`s.

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]:
   reference   name      lon     lat
0          0  name1  34.0055  1.0041
1          1  name1      NaN     NaN
2          2  name1  39.5632  3.6854

In [73]: df['city'] = df.apply(lambda x: (None, None) if np.isnan(x.lon) or np.isnan(x.lat) else getplace(x.lon, x.lat), axis=1)

In [74]: df
Out[74]:
   reference   name      lon     lat             city
0          0  name1  34.0055  1.0041  (None, Algeria)
1          1  name1      NaN     NaN     (None, None)
2          2  name1  39.5632  3.6854    (None, Spain)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your replay
You are right, I didn't see the name of the function was wrong.
Now it seems to work but I always get an error that says:
    IndexError: ('list index out of range', 'occurred at index 6')
The 'index' changes every time I execute the code. Is it possible that Google does not allow me to get the data in bulk??

Comment: What is the full traceback, and what are the values of the relevant local variables when it happens?

Comment: I have edited the original post to provide some more information. Thanks again!

Comment: @juancar: I get that error consistently for the second row in your input; that is, `results` is empty in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-3.691751,40.414181&sensor=false -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/20910075/5085211 might be helpful here.